How to update screen context in ForAll loop in power apps
I currently generate multiple screens in a Canvas app, in power apps from a collection of invoice records. Now I would like to iterate through the collection sending each of the invoices to a PDF file.
I have managed to loop and print to PDF, however the context is not updating as so each invoice has the same data.
How can I create a loop to go through collection and send the correct data to PDF for each record?
Thank you
ForAll(
    RecordsGallery1.AllItems,
        //Set(myPDF, PDF(PDF,{ExpandContainers:true}));
        Navigate(PDF);
        'PowerAppV2->Createfile'.Run(
            GUID() & ".pdf",
            {
                file: {
                    name: GUID() & ".pdf",
                    contentBytes: PDF(PDF)
                }
            }            
        );
        Navigate('Customs Invoice Record screen'); 
)

